# How to get data from an weather api and access it's data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, backend

I tried to get weather API data from this program,my problem is that this program's output is undefined,I expected an object,Why the output is undefined and how I can get the required object?

```
const url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=KEYREDACTED&q=London"
const url1 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New Delhi,India&appid=KEYREDACTED"

const apiRequest = https.get(url,(res) => {
  let data ="";
  res.on("data",(chunk) => {
      data+=chunk;
      JSON.parse(data);
  })
  res.on("end",() => {
      console.log(data.location);
  });
});
```

Comment: No expert on node.js, but shouldn't you first retrieve all the data and only then parse the JSON? The link you gave returns the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Important: Never include API Keys/IDs in your question (the part after `?key=` and `&appid=`). Other people can use them and use up your traffic.

You are parsing data using `JSON.parse` while the response is still being received. Move that to the `"end"` part.

```js
https.get(url,(res) => {
  let data ="";
  res.on("data",(chunk) => {
      // Data is being received in chunks, we add it to the data variable to save it
      data+=chunk;
  })
  res.on("end",() => {
    // all data has been received, now we can parse it and are done
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsedData);
  });
});
```

The `parsedData` is probably the object you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to add to the ffritz response which is correct and say that there are npm packages that will cut your work in half or just use pure ES6 and fetch which is also super simple and makes all that conversion work for you.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here is some documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch